# Complex BackgroundImage styling not working in react, but works in css/javascript

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This problem is extremely specific to this use case. All other cases I have been able to get to work properly, but for some reason this case does not work. Given a div 
`<div id="colorDiv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>` we can normally use in javascript: 
`let colDiv = document.getElementById("colorDiv");
colDiv.style.cssText = "background: green; background: linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 50%, green 0) top left, linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, green 0) top right, linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 50%, green 0) bottom right, linear-gradient(45deg,  transparent 50%, green 0) bottom left; background-size: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;";`
 (this will give a large green check mark). Anyway, I am trying to do this in React JS and I am tyring to get the value (here green) from an input (and should be predefined/stored in my reducer hook). Whenever I try to set the BackgroundImage property to this type of large value (given above), it never comes through on the output... Why would this be so, and how could you get this type of 4 linear gradients in-line with React.

Please note that I am able to get a single linear-gradient into the background image property in React and still having in-line styling, but having this type (with 4 of them, does not work). Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools DOM inspector?

Comment: @Andy Hoffman literally nothing, no warnings, no errors, no styling, nothing, just like as if there was no code being applied to the div. (note it does leave the className and id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different idea to do the same where you can keep most of the CSS outside and you only need one background as inline style:

```css
.colorDiv {
  background-size:0 0;
  display:inline-block;
}
.colorDiv::before,
.colorDiv::after{
  content:"";
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  background-image:inherit;
  transform:skewY(45deg);
  transform-origin:left;
}
.colorDiv::after {
  transform:skewY(-45deg);
  transform-origin:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorDiv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;background-image:linear-gradient(green,green)"></div>

<div class="colorDiv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;background-image:linear-gradient(red,red)"></div>

<div class="colorDiv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;background-image:linear-gradient(blue,blue)"></div>
```

Or simply use CSS variables with your code:

```css
.colorDiv {
 background: 
   linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 50%, var(--c,green) 0) top left, 
   linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 50%, var(--c,green) 0) top right, 
   linear-gradient(315deg, transparent 50%, var(--c,green) 0) bottom right, 
   linear-gradient(45deg , transparent 50%, var(--c,green) 0) bottom left;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="colorDiv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
<div class="colorDiv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;--c:red"></div>
<div class="colorDiv" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;--c:blue"></div>
```

Comment: this answer does not quite answer my question/meet my needs. The problem here is I need to be able to readily change the color, and I need to also be able to do many different shapes (not just this check mark). It also does not allow for mixing of colors (such as 4 different gradients to make a check). So not accepted but +1.

Comment: @SharpIncTechAndProgramming whataver the shape you will be using, you can do the same logic. There is no need to put a bunch of CSS inline. You can define the generic CSS and then adjust only few porperties and you can mix colors like you want. I gave 2 different method where the last one rely on CSS variables that allow you to do what you want

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I clearly overlooked one aspect of your code. This is now the accepted answer. Thank you very much for the help!